# Project templates in Gitlab upon creation

Tags: project, gitlab

What is the cleanest way to create a project in a self hosted gitlab with predefined (dynamically generated) files?

Concretely, I want to create a git repo on gitlab that upon creation contains all the files of a basic iOS project already. I just have to clone it and just start developing, instead of creating the project locally and then push it up to Gitlab.

Anyone?

I was looking into the gitlab-shell and the creation hook in gitlab-project: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/blob/master/lib/gitlab_projects.rb

Am I about to embark on a world of pain following this method? Is there something already out there that makes it easy to hook up at the application level?

Comment: have you found any solution to this?

Comment: It's almost builtin https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/48043

Comment: Otherwise create a python or your fav scripting language script that automates the local stuff by using the gitlab api? (or put it in a container)

Answer (score 1):

For **GitLab Premium** (self-hosted) (or GitLab Silver plan for gitlab.com) please see [Custom instance-level project templates](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/custom_project_templates.html), [available since Gitlab 11.2](https://about.gitlab.com/2018/08/22/gitlab-11-2-released/#custom-project-templates-on-the-instance-level).

Answer (score 1):

For **GitLab CE** (or EE too, if you need more features than the standard templates provide) I propose using this set of tools:

- configure [system hooks in GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/system_hooks/system_hooks.html) to make it fire a `POST` request on `project_create` events,
- set up [adnanh/webhook](https://github.com/adnanh/webhook) as a server that will receive these `POST` requests and then run [egnyte/gitlabform](https://github.com/egnyte/gitlabform) app to configure the new project,
- create configuration for gitlabform with any files you need. Example:

```
gitlab:
  url: https://gitlab.yourcompany.com
  # You can also set in your environment GITLAB_TOKEN
  # this can be both private token OR OAuth2 access token
  token: "<private token of an admin user>"
  api_version: 4

group_settings:
  # this assumes that you create your new iOS projects in a "ios" group in GitLab
  ios:
    files:
      "README.md":
        # this will prevent resetting the file to below contents if it has already been customized
        overwrite: false
        # this will prevent the commit that applies this file change triggering CI build
        skip_ci: true
        branches:
          - develop
        content: |
          This is a default project README. Please replace it with a proper one!
      "other-file":
        branches:
          - develop
        # You can provide file contents with external file too. Both absolute and relative paths are supported.
        # Relative paths are interpreted as relative to `config.yml` file location.
        file: some-file.txt
```

See https://github.com/egnyte/gitlabform for more info about the features, more examples and a full config syntax description.

Disclosure: I am the original author of egnyte/gitlabform app and I have contributed to adnanh/webhook and therefore I like them both. :)

Comment: Is it possible to use different `config.yml` based on the name of the repository, ignoring groups and subgroups? I'll try to explain better: I usually create my repo with this naming convention `customer-name/project-name/component`, where `component` can assume values like `swift-client`, `node-backend` with a fixed list. I would like to add some files to the repo if it's named `swift-client`, other files if it's named `node-backend` and so on.

Comment: maybe I could just deploy many instances of `egnyte/gitlabform`, each one with a specific configuration for each component, and implement this kind of logic on `adnanh/webhook` when I parse the paylod. Does it make sense? Is there a better way?

Comment: Hey @Gianluca! There is no such feature yet but I can imagine quite easily adding a feature to be able to provide config for projects with paths matching patternslike `*/*/swift-client`, `*/*/node-backend` etc. Please create an issue in `egnyte/gitlabform` and describe fully what you need.

Comment: ...but running gitlabform by using `adnanh/webhook` is a good idea too. :)

Answer (score 0):

See [GitLab 13.7](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/12/22/gitlab-13-7-released/#improved-ui-for-project-creation) (December 2020), available in GitLab CE (free)

> ### Improved UI for project creation
>
> The improved user interface for adding a project makes it easier to select between creating a blank project, starting a project from a template, importing an existing project, and creating a CI/CD-only project for external repositories.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/create-project.html#create-a-project-in-gitlab) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/210599).

This allows to create a project from a template easily:

[image: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/uploads/42faf9f5f0c8fb5157a89595ab9748f9/Import_1.0.png]

---

You have also, with [GitLab 14.8](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/02/22/gitlab-14-8-released/#add-default-issue-and-merge-request-templates-in-a-projects-repository) (February 2022):

> ### Add default issue and merge request templates in a project’s repository
>
> In addition to defining [default issue and merge request description templates](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/description_templates.html#set-a-default-template-for-merge-requests-and-issues) in project settings, you can now set default templates in the `.gitlab`
> directory of a project’s repository.
> Do it by creating a `Default.md` file in the issue or merge request templates folders.
> If default templates exist in both the project’s settings and in the repository, the template in the settings
> takes precedence.
>
> Thanks for the contribution `@davebarr`!
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/description_templates.html#set-a-default-template-for-merge-requests-and-issues) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/2557).